# Passport Renewal Data Question

Tags: us-citizens, passport-renewals

On the final box of the passport renewal application, "Has my data changed since your last document was issued?", does the question apply to my address or or just the information on the data page of the passport?

Comment: What form are you completing? The [US Passport Renewal Form DS-82](https://eforms.state.gov/Forms/ds82.pdf) doesn't appear to have such a checkbox.

Comment: Which country, that might be most important here.

Comment: @Willeke The OP selected the tag "us-citizens" when the question was posed, so I presumed it was a US process.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica The online version of the form asks this question.

Answer (score 18):

You are referring to a question on the online US passport renewal form filler, which reads:

> Has your data changed since your most recent document was issued?

If you click Yes, it will then ask you *which* specific data has changed since your last passport was issued.

[image]

The choices are:

- Last name
- First name
- Middle name
- Place of birth
- Date of birth
- Sex

You are not prompted again for the specifics, as you should have already supplied the new data (and the old data, when specifically asked for it) in previous questions.

Comment: (side note, curious ) Do the choices only appear when the user selects "Yes"? if so it's a bad UI/UX

Comment: @Max Yes, that's how the web site was designed. And of course it's bad UI/UX. It's an American government web site.